# Declared optional arguments, get error anyway (cs1501)

Tags: c#, optional-arguments

Is there something wrong with my method declaration?

```
protected void MyMethod<T>(List<T> props, MyDelegate pa, Rect location = default (Rect), bool newButton = false) where T : MyClass, new() {
...
}
```

Yet whenever I try to just pass the two arguments I get the following error:
"error CS1501: No overload for method "MyMethod" takes "2" arguments"

What's going on?

EDIT: As requested, the method call looks like this:

```
private void CallingMethod () {
    List<MyDerivedClass> listOfMyDerivedClass = new List<MyDerivedClass>({.....});
    MyDelegate del = MyOtherMethod;
    MyMethod<MyDerivedClass>(listOfMyDerivedClass, del);
}

private void MyOtherMethod (...) {
....
}
```

EDIT: I should add that the method works as intended if I just provide the full 4 parameters. It gives me the same if I just give 3 though.

Comment: Can you show how your call looks like ?

Comment: Sounds like you have an overload in a derived class.

Comment: please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Which version of VS are you using? Optional parameters aren't supported in versions older than VS2010.

Comment: I'm not using VS, I'm using Unity and MonoDevelop. I also added the method call.

Comment: Which version of the C# compiler are you using? Also, is `MyMethod` declared in a base class of the class that declares `CallingMethod`?

Comment: I have no idea. Unity and/or MonoDevelop handle all the compiling. MyMethod is declared in the base class. CallingMethod is declared in a derived class. (They are not the same as MyClass and MyDerivedClass though)

Comment: If you remove your invocation of the method, leaving the default parameter values in place, does the code compile?

Comment: Yes, the code does compile.